# How to hide group conversation?

Tags: skype

How do I hide a group conversation from the "recent" sidebar, without leaving it?

Comment: does [this](https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/Can-t-hide-chat-conversations/td-p/3584681) help you?

we need more information as to what else is wrong.

Comment: @RegisteredUser I was on the Skype forums. Their information is disgustingly outdated, so figured I'd try StackExchange.